# OMNET++ Could not load images

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am a fresh man new to OMNET++ , but I am crazy about the error below, due to which I can't run my single tic-toc simulation according to the tutorial... I searched google, but nobody else have the same problem.
The error message is:

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2018 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.4.1, build: 180629-5e28390, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

Setting up Qtenv...

Loading NED files from .:  1
Loading NED files from ../src:  2

Loading images from '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images': *: 0  abstract/*: 90  background/*: 4  block/*: 320  device/*: 195  logo/*: 1  maps/*: 9  misc/*: 70  msg/*: 55  old/*: 111 Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/app.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ball.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ball2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ball2_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ball2_vs.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ball_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ball_vs.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bluebox.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/box1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/box1_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/box2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/box2_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/box3.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/box3_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/browser.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwcomp.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwcomp_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwgen.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwgen_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwsink.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwsink_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwxcon_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/bwxconn.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/card1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/card2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/cloud.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/cloud_l.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/cloud_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/cogwheel.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/cogwheel2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/cogwheel2_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/comp.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/comp2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/comp2_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/comp_a.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/comp_a_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/comp_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/delay.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/dialphone.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/drive1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/drive2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/earth1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/floppy1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/floppy2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/folder.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/fork.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/gen.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/greenbox.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/handset1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/handset1_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/handset2_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/harddisk.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/hook.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/iface.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ipc.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/laptop.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/laptop2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/laptop2_l.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/laptop3.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/mailbox.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/monitor.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pc.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pc_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pccard.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pccard_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pctower1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pctower2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pda1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pda2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/pda3.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/penguin.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/printer.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/proc1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/proc2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/prot1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/prot2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/prot3.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/queue.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/redbox.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/ring.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/router.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/router2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/router2_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/router3.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/router_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/server1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/server1_l.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/sink.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/srouter.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/switch1.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/switch1_s.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/switch2.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/telnet.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_active.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_asleep.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_blank.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_busy.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_check.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_cross.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_down.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_excl.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_green.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_hglass.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_noentry.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_off.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_question.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_red.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_smoke.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_up.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/x_yellow.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/old/xconn.gif'
 status/*: 28 Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/active.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/asleep.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/busy.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/check.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/cross.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/down.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/excl.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/green.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/hourglass.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/lightning.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/noentry.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/off.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/question.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/red.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/smoke.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/up.gif'
Could not load image '/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images/status/yellow.gif'


This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 134
Working directory: /Users/junpan/samples/PJtictoc/simulations
Command line: ../src/PJtictoc -m -n .:../src omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/bin::/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/lib::
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/Users/junpan/omnetpp-5.4.1/images
```

I thought maybe my omnet++ installation is not complete, but I tried to reinstall the OMNET++ from the official page, and I updated QT recently but it doesn't work. QT can be ran independently. The images required by the error code doesn't exist in the directory, but I didn't call them in my code, how can a simple tic-toc need such images?
What should I do now?
this guy have the same problem but it is still unsolved...
[unsolved google group problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/omnetpp/omnetpp/lGQd8qD8rNQ)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by explicitly set `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` in run configurations to the qt that bundled with omnet++ (YourOmnetppDirectory/tools/macosx/plugins/). Works for macOS.

[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the QT installation bundled with OMNeT++ cannot find it's plugins so in turn cannot load the default OMNeT++ images on the simulator start. Make sure that you have properly followed the installation guide. The bundled QT libraries are set up during the OMNeT++ configuration process (i.e. while you are running ./configure). At that point the configure script sets the location of the plug-in automatically. In short, be sure that:

extract the tgz file un your home dir

```
$ . setenv
$ ./configure
$ make -j=8 
$ cd samples/aloha
$ ./aloha
```

try to run the sample there to see whether Qtenv works correctly.

Alternatively for a workaround: Use Tkenv (which is the old Tk based environment). I.e. start the simulation with:

```
$ ./aloha -u Tkenv
```

Comment: I am able to start the samples, but can not start my own simulation. Any idea why that is the case?